# Не подключаются стили для домашней amp-страницы в functions.php

Tags: wordpress, amp

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    if ( function_exists('is_amp_endpoint') && is_amp_endpoint() ) {

        if (is_front_page()) {

            $css_to_off =

                [
                    'amp-default',
                    'font-awesome-4-7',
                    'main-styles-inline',
                    'responsive',
                    'js_composer_front',
                    'js_composer.min',
                    'wp-custom',
                    'related-post',
                    'font-awesome-5',
                    'main-styles',
                    'magnific',
                    'parent-style'
                ];

            foreach ($css_to_off as $item) {
                wp_dequeue_style($item);
                wp_deregister_style($item);
            }

            //проверка адреса
            echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/amp/home.min.css';
            wp_enqueue_style('home-amp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/amp/home.css');
        }
    }
}, 1000 );
```

Этот код я использую, чтобы проверить, является ли страница домашней и amp ли она, отключаю все стили по id и подключаю стили соответствующей страницы. Но они не подключаются. То есть, условие правильное, стили из массива удаляются, адрес указан правильный, и он выводится. Если добавить условие `else` (что страница не amp) и добавить  вышеуказанную строку `wp_enqueue_style('home-amp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/amp/home.css');`, то стиль добавится. Че за дела? В чем может быть причина? Куда копнуть? Спасибо за любую помощь!

Может они подключаются, но почему-то не выводятся (например, .test не найден)

Comment: АМП - это не стандартный WordPress. Что вы используете для создания AMП-страниц? Ищите нужные хуки внутри вашего АМП плагина

Answer (score 0):

Моя ошибка была в том, что я использовал несуществующий селектор .test, предполагая, что он выведется. А amp автоматически, если такого селектора нет, удаляет неиспользуемые стили. Поэтому я не видел стили для .test.